# Posts and order

Tags: posts, order

newbie here with quick question, looking at all my pages if I click on quick edit I have the chance to place a number on the field order and set an order on which one should appear first,then second, so on so on, tried to do the same on posts but that option is not available, any idea on how to make it appear?

Thanks

Arturo

P.S.: Oh, for this one I'm using wordpress 2.9.2

Comment: Posts are ordered by date.

Comment: Unrelated: Your site will be hacked soon if you don’t run an upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is [`page-attributes` support in the post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_type_support). However...

> 'page-attributes' (<strike>template and</strike> menu order) (hierarchical must be
>   true) (the page template selector is only available for the page post
>   type)

... and posts are not hierarchical. I am not sure you can force them to be, never mind the potential issues with altering a built in post type like that.

Additionally, that 'order' values in not used very much by default, and certainly not by "post" post type queries so you'd need to alter a number of queries to get that to work. I think there are hooks enough to do it but it would be a bit of work.

My advise is that if you need another page-like post type, [just create one](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type).

Answer (score 0):

While it's true WP posts are sorted by date or something else if you use custom query maybe you can take advantage of WordPress [sticky posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Sticky_Posts). This option allows you to shed light on particular article so they are put to the top of front-page posts.